# Partial fractions: why does $\int dt \implies t + C$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I am working on a partial fraction problem here, I understand everything in the problem except $t+C$, so I'd like to know where did  the $t+C$ come from ?

I want to solve this integral
$$
\int \frac{dy}{(y+2)(1-y)} = \int dt
$$

$$\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{A}{y+2} + \frac{B}{1-y} \\
1 &= A(1-y) + B(y+2)
\end{align}$$

Let $y=1$, then $1=B(3)$ and $B=1/3$.

Let $y=-2$, then $1=A(3)$ and $A=1/3$

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1/3}{y+2} + \frac{1/3}{1-y} \;dy &= \int dt\\
\frac{1}{3}(\ln|y+2| - \ln|1-y|) &= \color{red}{t+C} & \text{?}\\
\ln\left|\frac{y+2}{1-y}\right| &=3(t+C)\\
\frac{y+2}{1-y} = Ce^{3t}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @TooTone Cut some slack, already! It's good that the OP is showing his/her work. If you find the notes hard to read, I take it you don't teach?

Comment: @amWhy What I wrote was wrong. I got all enthusiastic about that link after seeing it posted for the first time last night but nevertheless I should simply have edited the post.

Comment: @TooTone thanks for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original equation is $$\int \frac{dy}{(y+2)(1-y)} = \int \,dt$$
$t + C$ comes from integrating the righthand side of the original equation: $$\int \,dt = t + C$$

The $C$ is the constant of integration.

Comment: I do understand that almost the entire problem focuses on the left-hand side of the original equation, and so the right-hand may have gotten "lost in the shuffle"/over-looked.

Answer (score 2):

Think of $\int dt$ as $\int1dt$. The integral of $1$ with respect to any variable is that variable, so in this case, $\int1dt$ is $t+C$. Where $C$ is a constant.